# C Linux fscanf not reading all of line

Tags: c, linux, string, scanf

I'm working with some code written by someone else to scan key value string pairs from a config file.  The code is:

```
void readProfile(char * profileName) {
    FILE *f;
    int i=0;
    f = fopen(profileName, "r");
    if (NULL != f) {
        while (fscanf(f, "%s%s", &pvtProperties[i].key[0],
                &pvtProperties[i].value[0]) == 2) {
            i++;
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
    numberOfProperties = i;
    setCurrentProfileName(profileName);
}
```

However when reading this plaintext config file below, it has a problem with the 4th line:, the value is truncated to "https://dev.xxxx.com:58443/services/PvtTransferSer".  Each line of the config file is separated by \r\n.  From that point on the reading of the rest of the file is messed up, values becoming keys etc.  Why is this happening?  The keys and values are char arrays of 80 chars each.

Config file:

```
PASSWORD xxxx
REMOTE_UPDATES_ENABLE 1
REMOTE_DIAGNOSTICS_ENABLE 1
PVT_TRANSFER_WS_ADDRESS https://www.xxxx.com:58443/services/PvtTransferService
PVT_DIAGNOSTIC_WS_ADDRESS https://www.xxxx.com:58443/services/PvtDiagnosticService
PVT_UPDATE_WS_ADDRESS https://www.xxxx.com:58443/services/PvtUpdateService
PVT_ADJUSTMENT_WS_ADDRESS https://www.xxxx.com:58443/services/PvtAdjustmentService
DAILY_RESTART_ENABLE  1
HOUR_PAST_MIDNIGHT_FOR_RESTART 7
MAX_RESTART_RANDOMIZATION_SECONDS 30
MINIMUM_UPTIME_SECONDS_BETWEEN_RESTARTS 7200
CLEAR_CACHE_ON_RESTART_ENABLE 0
MINIMUM_SECONDS_BETWEEN_REMOTE_UPDATE_CHECKS 3600
SECONDS_BETWEEN_CONTROLLER_CONFIGURATION_CHECKS 300
CONNECTIVITY_LOSS_DETECTION_ENABLE 1
SMART_COMM_ENABLE 1
TIME_SYNC_ENABLE 1
FACTORY_RESET_ENABLE 1
CM_POLL_PROTOCOL http
```

Comment: You mean 4th line or 4th pair? It's not the same thing - the first line has 3 pairs.

Comment: This `&pvtProperties[i].key[0]` is just this `pvtProperties[i].key`. Ditto with value.

Comment: How long is the buffer in `pvtProperties[i].value[0]`?

Comment: Re-edited the config. file the paste was messed up.  Both key and value are char[80] arrays.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves, Just seems more canonical to write it the other way. Why overcomplicate things?

Comment: @EOF What do you mean? `%s` stops reading as soon as it hits a whitespace, and `fscanf()` terminates the string when writing it to the buffer.

Comment: fscanf of %s%s is breaking splitting up the key and value by the space char and is almost working.  It's just truncating the value for the key on the 4th line.

Comment: Try `%[^ \t] %[^ \r\n]` instead of `%s%s`

Comment: Best guess -- you have some non-printing whitespace character in the file between the `r` and `v`.  Look at the config file in a binary editor to see if anything odd is there.

Comment: I checked the file in bvi and can't see any strange characters...

Comment: How big is `pvtProperties[i].key` and `pvtProperties[i].value`?  Suggest that they are too small.  If there are say 20 and 30 `char`, then use `"%19s%29s"` to prevent over-run.  NM I see "The keys and values are char arrays of 80 chars each."  Suggest "%79s%79s"`

Comment: 1) Suspect the issue is not with the code posted but with how memory is allocated for `pvtProperties[i]` or something that is colliding with it. 2) Posting the return value from `fscanf()` helps, is it EOF, 0 or 1 on failure?

Comment: @chux: according to the code posted and the description of the problem, `fscanf()` is returning 2 because otherwise it wouldn't continue to read read from the file.

Comment: @Michael Burr True, but eventfully the loop ends.  If it ends on EOF and has phase issues that hints to more than one read problem.  If it ends on 1, it helps to imply a single (or odd number) of messed  up lines.  OP was not descriptive with the last line of the file other than "rest of the file is messed up, values becoming keys etc."

Comment: Based on "the value is truncated", it sounds like you have run off the end of an array (either `pvtProperties`, or a `.key` or `.value`). Please post the declarations and allocation of `pvtProperties` and the code that calls this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your phase issue by using fgets to pull a line in at a time from the file; then sscanf to parse that line buffer for each record.